# PCF Unable to use Config Server and Service Registry together in an Application

Tags: spring-boot, pcfdev

I am trying to bind the PCF Config Server and PCF Service registry in the same Application and push the app . However I get an error while the application is starting . The problem is due to the application unable to send the Hertbeat information and it fails with unable to refresh cache.

If i bind config server alone and Service registry alone it works but when both the services are bound it fails.

Any help with this is appreciated

The dependencies are as follows

```
            <parent>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
                <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
            </parent>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-starter-service-registry</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-starter-config-client</artifactId>
            </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved after gave the Service registry to take the path using the following configuration
    spring.cloud.services.registrationMethod=route